# Using apostrophes

Tags: punctuation, apostrophe

Hey guys! I hope you can help.  For homework, I was asked to write an essay using some words the teacher gave in class and the last word I need to use is *country*. Can someone please tell—does *country* need to have an apostrophe-s at the end of the word? And is the following sentence I wrote correct?

> The country's best pizza, is served at buca.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Apostrophe yes, comma no.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to capitalize the first word of each sentence and each occurrence of the word 'I'.  It helps keep this site more professional. Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, you could always use `The best pizza in the country is served at Buca.`. Cleaner and no issue on apostrophes there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some simple apostrophe rules

- A plural, such as "Dogs" to describe many Dogs, uses *no apostrophe*. For your example, though, the word country becomes countries when describing more than one country (and ending in 'y' becomes 'ies' rule, I think)
- "It's" is a contraction of it is, and so uses *apostrophe s*
- "Harry's" describes something possessed by Harry, e.g Harry's foot.

  This can be a tricky one to remember, as it is a contraction of "Harry his (foot)" (a term that is never used any more in its expanded sense), and country's is also a contraction of the odd sounding "country his (or hers)". As this is a contraction, we use *apostrophe s*

  Using this rule we see that you are correct in using "country's"
- Charles' describes something possessed by Charles (abbreviation used instead of Charles's) If you don't want to use  s's, then we use *s apostrophe*
- "Its" is the exception to the possession (apostrophe s) rule, presumably as "It his" is a contradictory gender statement, so use *no apostrophe*

Answer (score 5):

Your use of the apostrophe in "the country's best pizza" is correct. But it is all wrong as regards punctuation and capitals.