# The difference between "It's" and "It is"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "It's" and "It is"?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One is a contraction of the other.

Comment: Closely related, and possible duplicate of   [Concerning: its'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297372/concerning-its) but the answer has been heavily downvoted (quite unfairly too)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using apostrophes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15930/using-apostrophes)

Comment: One important difference is discussed at [Is there some rule against ending a sentence with the contraction "it's"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/500/is-there-some-rule-against-ending-a-sentence-with-the-contraction-its); the acceptability per se of common contractions is doubtless already covered elsewhere.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Nothing, outside of it being taboo to use contractions in formal writing. Additionally, it has been brought to light that the use of the contraction at the end of a sentence would also be awkward or incorrect, however, I do not know of any formal rule to this. Finally, "It's" may also act as a contraction for "It has", as well as "It is." If "It's" is followed by a past participle it may be a contraction for "It has."

Comment: So "We need to decide what it's" is acceptable in informal registers?

Comment: A good example that did not cross my mind.

Comment: You've improved the answer, but the problems remain that both it and the question here have been given before, and both lack any signs of research / supporting evidence.

Comment: His question is his research. As for supporting evidence, this is not a scientific issue. Are you asking for me to cite the Oxford rules on the contraction itself? Or the questions pertaining to this that are listed to the right of this entry; that explain under similar questions that there is no formal rule about ending sentences in contractions. Are you asking for examples?

Comment: I suggest you read up on what are considered poor and good answers at the help center.